# Value cannot be null. Parameter name URL on ASP.net form submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a ASP.net webform with few controls and when I hit the submit button I am getting the following error

sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:url

On submit of the button I am just inserting values into the database.

How do I fix this issue?

When I try to put a breakpoint on page load it says No symbols have been loaded for this document.

HTML for the submit button is shown below

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" />
```

Please help

Comment: Can you post the submit button html in the question and also check if you are doing a redirection without a url specified.

Comment: And I noticed one more thing. It is not coming to the break point I have on the submit button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="btnSubmit_Click" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit" />
```

Comment: Welcome to the site - in order for code to display properly you need to indent each line with four spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help